# Как правильно сделать форматирование текста

Tags: python

у меня есть файл `slowa.txt` и небольшое содержание `я,ок,чел,челты,лох,лол,лоlь,трол,клоуниха`
мне нужно заменить , на перенос на другую строчку, вот как должно это выглядеть

```
я
ок
чел
челты
лох
лол
лолlь 
трол
клоуниха
```

как это сделать, просто слов много, а я уже устал :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file = open("slowa.txt")
data = file.read().replace(',','\n')
file.close()
file = open("slowa.txt","w")
file.write(data)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]